# How to handle video_note in aiogram?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

I could not handle the video_note in aiogram with FMS. Help me what is wrong???
So, I want to save video_note id then send it to other users how else I can do that?
Sorry if my question wrong its my first question on stack overflow...

```
async def set_circle(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['user_circle'] = message.video_note.file_id
await FSMUserRegistration.next()
await message.answer('Done!')

async with state.proxy() as data:
    await message.answer(str(data))


def register_handlers_user(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(set_circle, content_types=['video_note'], state=FSMUserRegistration.user_circle)
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example